# Possible to store timestamps as keys in Hash and make it sortable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have a Comment model which the user can edit. I'd like to save every new version of the comment, much how it works in Facebook.

Instead of having an associated model where I create a new record for every new submitted edit, I was thinking to use Active Model's [Serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) and insert a Hash key/value-pair for every new edit.

The submitted text would be the value and time of the edit would be the key.

Is it possible to save a DateTime value as a key and then be able to sort the Hash chronologically by the keys? And if positive, how would I create the keys?

Comment: I would not recommend to use serialization in this case. Using 2 distinct models, `Comment` and `CommentVersion`(which holds the current comment's value), will be much more flexible that a serialized Hash/Array, which would need a specific treatment to retrive, update, delete, create, etc. Also, if the serialized Hash/Array is getting very big, you'll end up with too much data for a single column and your DB adapter will have to use a trick to store everything.

Comment: Yes, it's much more powerful to have two different models but I'm still curious if this is possible. (I would limit the number of edits to a handful edits.)

Comment: @Numbers if you are using pg, then I think it's possible. They have json field and it's sortable by keys as well.

Comment: Yes it is possible but it will be way more complex to manage this instead of a basic validation on the edits count. In my opinion, you should stick with the 2 models strategy, but you can use serialization too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments about it being odd, but yes, it can be done in Ruby. You can set a [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html) object as the key to a hash like so:

```
hash = {}
hash[Time.now] = 'value'
hash
#=> {2015-09-30 11:45:41 -0500=>1}
```

If your time was initialized as a string, you can parse it into a `Time` object using:

```
Time.parse("12:00")
#=> 2015-09-30 12:00:00 -0500
```

Finally, hashes in Ruby maintain order since version 1.8 or 1.9, but are **not** sortable, so you can create an array of just the keys using `Hash#keys` and then sort the keys:

```
hash = {}
hash[Time.now] = 'value'
hash[Time.now] = 'value2'
hash[Time.now] = 'value3'
hash[Time.now] = 'value4'
hash[Time.now] = 'value5'
hash
#=> {
      2015-09-30 11:50:17 -0500=>"value",
      2015-09-30 11:50:18 -0500=>"value2",
      2015-09-30 12:04:05 -0500=>"value3",
      2015-09-30 12:04:04 -0500=>"value4",
      2015-09-30 12:04:06 -0500=>"value5",
    }

hash.keys
#=> [
      2015-09-30 11:50:17 -0500
      2015-09-30 11:50:18 -0500,
      2015-09-30 12:04:05 -0500,
      2015-09-30 12:04:04 -0500,
      2015-09-30 12:04:06 -0500,
    ]

shuffled_keys = hash.keys.shuffle
#=> [
      2015-09-30 12:04:04 -0500,
      2015-09-30 12:04:06 -0500,
      2015-09-30 11:50:18 -0500,
      2015-09-30 12:04:05 -0500,
      2015-09-30 11:50:17 -0500
    ]

latest_key = shuffled_keys.sort.last
#=> 2015-09-30 12:04:06 -0500

hash[latest_key]
#=> "value5"
```